# Sorting an arrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have to sort an arraylist by the date and time entered by the user but for some reason the output comes out not in order

Below this code it the code im using to order

```
public int compareTo(Vehicle v){
    int returnValue = 0;
    if (this.parkDate.year> v.parkDate.getYear() && 
            this.parkDate.month> v.parkDate.getMonth() &&
            this.parkDate.day> v.parkDate.getDay() &&
            this.parkDate.hours> v.parkDate.getHours() &&
            this.parkDate.minuets> v.parkDate.getMinuets()){
        returnValue =  1; }
    else
        returnValue = - 1;
    return returnValue;
}
```

[image: Here is the output message]

Comment: You should really store Calendar or Date objects, not integers for each datetime part yourself...

Comment: well, if everything is the same but one minute is greater, that statement would return -1 instead of 1. You need to consider equal cases, and there's hierarchy here (if a month is less, it doesn't matter if it's a year ahead). You should use one of the available time apis in java (Date, joda time, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison logic isn't correct. You might perform your comparisons with `Integer.compare(int, int)` and `return` the result in the case of non-zero. Something like,

```
public int compareTo(Vehicle v) {       
    int returnValue = Integer.compare(this.parkDate.getYear(), 
            v.parkDate.getYear());
    if (returnValue != 0) {
        return returnValue;
    }
    returnValue = Integer.compare(this.parkDate.getMonth(), 
            v.parkDate.getMonth());
    if (returnValue != 0) {
        return returnValue;
    }
    returnValue = Integer.compare(this.parkDate.getDay(), 
            v.parkDate.getDay());
    if (returnValue != 0) {
        return returnValue;
    }
    returnValue = Integer.compare(this.parkDate.getHours(), 
            v.parkDate.getHours());
    if (returnValue != 0) {
        return returnValue;
    }
    return Integer.compare(this.parkDate.getMinuets(), 
            v.parkDate.getMinuets());
}
```

**Or**, you could shorten the above by using arrays and something like

```
int[] a = { this.parkDate.getYear(), this.parkDate.getMonth(), 
        this.parkDate.getDay(), this.parkDate.getHours(), 
        this.parkDate.getMinuets() };
int[] b = { v.parkDate.getYear(), v.parkDate.getMonth(), 
        v.parkDate.getDay(), v.parkDate.getHours(), 
        v.parkDate.getMinuets() };
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int rv = Integer.compare(a[i], b[i]);
    if (rv != 0) {
        return rv;
    }
}
return 0;
```

**Finally**, I believe you want **minutes** *not* **minuets**.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is your comparison logic. You are testing that your vehicle's park date's year is greater than the other vehicle's park date's year *and* your vehicle's park date's month is greater than the other vehicle's park date's month *and* ditto for the day, hour and minute. This is incorrect.

Consider `2016-01-01 00:00` and `2015-12-31 23:59`. The former clearly comes *after* the latter, but its month, day, hour and minute are all *less than* the other. Your logic would therefore fail to produce the correct result in this instance.

A more suitable approach would be to:

- compare the years: if they are different you can return a result, ie. less than or greater than
- if they are the same, compare the months; if they are different you can return a result
- if they are the same, compare the days; if they are different you can return a result
- if they are the same, compare the hours; if they are different you can return a result
- if they are the same, compare the minutes; if they are different you can return a result
- if they are the same, indicate the dates are equal

(Also, make sure you remembered to `implement Comparable` on your `Vehicle` class.)

Comment: Yes I have done Implement Comparable and I get what your saying and have tried to change it but it just comes up with errors Is there anything you can suggest

Comment: @AlexBurrows I've updated my answer with a pseudo-coded solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have an  error in your boolean logic.

```
if (this.parkDate.year> v.parkDate.getYear() && 
        this.parkDate.month> v.parkDate.getMonth() &&
        this.parkDate.day> v.parkDate.getDay() &&
        this.parkDate.hours> v.parkDate.getHours() &&
        this.parkDate.minuets> v.parkDate.getMinuets()){
    returnValue =  1; }
else
    returnValue = - 1;
```

Else is like taking the [negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) of your `if` statement. In this case that equates to the following:

```
this.parkDate.year <= v.parkDate.getYear()
```

OR

```
this.parkDate.month <= v.parkDate.getMonth()
```

OR

```
this.parkDate.day> v.parkDate.getDay()
...
```

In other words

```
Negation(A && B) <=> (Negation(A) || Negation(B))
```

In the context of your situation, your `else` logic could be true even if the year is greater than `this.parkDate`

I think this should be enough to help you get it right. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use "compareTo" the result is 0, 1, -1

```
public int compareTo(Vehicle a, Vehicle b){
    return a.parkDate.compareTo(b.parkDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the date and time as primitives, you can create a `LocalDateTime` and use it in `Comparator`

add field `parkDate` as `LocalDateTime` in `Vehicle` class

```
LocalDateTime parkDate = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute, second);
```

use the `parkDate` in `compareTo` method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Vehicle o) {       
    return this.parkDate.compareTo(o.parkDate);
}
```